# Python Convert class<str> to class <bytes>

Tags: python, arrays, string, byte

I have this string value with class :

```
key = "b'\x81*u\x11\xe8k\xef\xbc\xc6\xef\x9d\x83\x9f!\x0ej'"
```

I want it to convert to with class

```
key = b'\x81*u\x11\xe8k\xef\xbc\xc6\xef\x9d\x83\x9f!\x0ej'
```

How will I do it in Python? Any would be very much appreciated.

Comment: probably with `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: How did you produce `key` to begin with? It seems like you should fix whatever is giving you that output

Comment: Probably the backslashes are escaped as well?

Comment: this was clearly supposed to be bytes and someone wanted to guarantee a str so they did `str(my_bytes)` rather than `my_bytes.decode('latin1')` assuming you dont really just want it to be bytes anyway

Comment: Strange, I cannot find a proper dupe. Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the provider of `key` should be fixed to store the value and not the *representation* of the bytes

Anyway, to undo that, you can use the reverse, which is `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast

key = r"b'\x81*u\x11\xe8k\xef\xbc\xc6\xef\x9d\x83\x9f!\x0ej'"
print(ast.literal_eval(key))
```

which prints:

```
b'\x81*u\x11\xe8k\xef\xbc\xc6\xef\x9d\x83\x9f!\x0ej'
```

note that I had to use the raw prefix on the `key` bytes literal, which probably matches the input data you have.

This fix doesn't replace a proper fix of the whole chain: converting to representation and parsing it back has a cost CPU-wise.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of your `key` variable is literally `"b'\x81*u\x11\xe8k\xef\xbc\xc6\xef\x9d\x83\x9f!\x0ej'"` (rather than `r"b'\x81*u\x11\xe8k\xef\xbc\xc6\xef\x9d\x83\x9f!\x0ej'"` that @Jean-FrançoisFabre's answer presumes), you can use `int.to_bytes` to convert the characters in `key` to bytes after stripping the first two and the last characters (which are `b'` and `'`):

```
b''.join(ord(c).to_bytes(1, 'big') for c in key[2:-1])
```

This returns:

```
b'\x81*u\x11\xe8k\xef\xbc\xc6\xef\x9d\x83\x9f!\x0ej'
```